# SOAP web client returns part of url

Tags: java, android, webservice-client

I have a `SOAP` web service client I'm trying to get working and when it returns back the text it just returns part of the url. When I hit a button I want it to call the basic `HelloWorld` function and return the text in a `TextView` Here is what I have so far:

```
public void getMessage() {
    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private final String URL = "http://foobar/foo/Service1.asmx";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";

    private static String message;

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    //Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    //Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        //Invoke web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        //Get the response
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        message = result.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        tv.setText(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When it returns the answer all I get is `foobar`.why it is giving like this?

LogCat:

```
07-10 13:29:54.084: W/System.err(12041): java.net.UnknownHostException: fd5189
07-10 13:29:54.094: W/System.err(12041):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
07-10 13:29:54.094: W/System.err(12041):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
07-10 13:29:54.094: W/System.err(12041):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
07-10 13:29:54.094: W/System.err(12041):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:69)
07-10 13:29:54.094: W/System.err(12041):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
07-10 13:29:54.094: W/System.err(12041):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:322)
07-10 13:29:54.104: W/System.err(12041):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
07-10 13:29:54.104: W/System.err(12041):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
07-10 13:29:54.104: W/System.err(12041):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
07-10 13:29:54.104: W/System.err(12041):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
07-10 13:29:54.104: W/System.err(12041):    at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:46)
07-10 13:29:54.104: W/System.err(12041):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:68)
07-10 13:29:54.114: W/System.err(12041):    at com.example.mysoap.MainActivity.getMessage(MainActivity.java:129)
07-10 13:29:54.114: W/System.err(12041):    at com.example.mysoap.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:65)
07-10 13:29:54.114: W/System.err(12041):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2482)
07-10 13:29:54.114: W/System.err(12041):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9077)
07-10 13:29:54.114: W/System.err(12041):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-10 13:29:54.114: W/System.err(12041):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-10 13:29:54.124: W/System.err(12041):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-10 13:29:54.124: W/System.err(12041):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-10 13:29:54.124: W/System.err(12041):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 13:29:54.124: W/System.err(12041):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-10 13:29:54.124: W/System.err(12041):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-10 13:29:54.124: W/System.err(12041):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-10 13:29:54.124: W/System.err(12041):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It does not return a text as it is a void function. Please explain better which text/variable you are talking about.

Comment: `message`, when I step through the code it jumps out of the try at the line `androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);`

Comment: So it is not returning anything to begin with. And if it 'jumps out' of the try block then is it catched? If so what is the exception? Enable the e.printStackTrace() and look in the LogCat. You will see nice big red error lines. Post the logcat here please. Start with ` private static String message = null;` And check for null before use. What does tv display now? The exception i would think. You must have seen it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay... There is no red in the logcat, but when I step through it the exception says that its from an `unknownhostexception`

Comment: Well what does that mean do you think? And wasn't it an UnknownHostException ? And didn't you see that on the textview? According to your code in the catch block you should. And you will find the exception in the LogCat too. Red, blue, black or what ever color it is. Dit you remove the // before e.printStackTrace() as I asked for? Please reply to all suggestions/comments. We don't write them for fun.

Comment: I think it means it cant find the host that I'm trying to connect to in the web service. I tried to ping the server name and it did work. I removed the // from the code and in the logCat it says a whole bunch of `System.err` I'll post it so you can see exactly what it is.

Comment: OK. It cannot find the webservice. So now it is time you tell exactly your setup: This Android code is running on Emulator/Device/Phone? Where is the server running: Internet/On your pc. What do you use for host or ip address to connect to? The host is 'foobar' in `"http://foobar/foo/Service1.asmx";`.

Comment: I have an old android phone (2.3.4) it's old I know but it still works with other web service just isn't connecting to mine... I set it up through IIS so I believe over the internet... When I set it up I left hostname blank and for ip i left it at all unassigned

Comment: How can you ever let the host name blank if you want to connect to a host? So 'foobar' in the url is empty? Thst can never work. Moreover i cannot understand why you don't know if the webservice is somewhere on the internet or on your own pc. If you want help than come to the point! Or is foobar an ip address? Can you reach the webservice when you use the url in a browser on your phone?

Comment: Well I've never done web service set up before so I'm really new to it so I'm not quite sure about some of the features... when I set it up I left it blank. When I go to the url on my pc I can access it, I just tried to access the url on my phone and it cant find the page so I'm gonna say its localhost rather than internet

Comment: So you did set the webservive up yourself!? Well then you will know if you did it on your own pc or on a computer somwhere on the internet. Why dont you tell the exact url you used? You will save my time.